# How change background color of JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I can't change the background color of a JFrame, or of a JPanel inside the JFrame, this is my code:

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    public MyFrame(){
        setSize(600,600);
        setResizable(false);
        panel = new MyPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        //getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK); doesn't work
        getContentPane().add(panel);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent ev){
                System.exit(-1);
            }
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent ev){
                System.exit(-1);
            }
        });
    }

 public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        g.clearRect(0,0,600,600);
        synchronized (this){
            if (positions!=null){
                for (int i=0; i<positions.length; i++){
                    P2d p = positions[i];
                    //int x0 = (int)(180+p.x*180);
                    //int y0 = (int)(180-p.y*180);
                    g.drawOval((int)p.x,(int)p.y,5,5);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i have tried in several ways, but I can not change the color, it's always white, how i can do?

Comment: `panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);` should work. Show your MyPanel class

Comment: @kleopatra the question you linked deals with `JFrame` and although this question's title might be misleading, assuming OP's MyPanel follows suit of MyFrame and extends `JPanel` this question appears to be about changing the color of a `JPanel` not working at its core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one. Draw a rectangle filled with your background color.

- use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` or `EventQueue.invokeLater()`
- use `paintComponent()` method for custom painting
- don't draw on `JFrame` directly.
- use `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)` to close the `JFrame`

Sample code:

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    public MyFrame() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                setSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
                setResizable(false);
                JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
                    @Override
                    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                        super.paintComponent(g);

                        g.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
                        Color prevColor = g.getColor();

                        g.setColor(Color.BLUE); // background color
                        g.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 600); // fill a rectangle with background color
                        g.setColor(prevColor);

                        // your custom painting
                        ...
                    }
                };
                getContentPane().add(panel);
                setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @kleopatra Have you read the link?

Comment: thanks, it works, why i have to use SwingUtilities.invokeLater() or EventQueue.invokeLater()? and why i have to use paintComponent instead of paint?

Comment: Just search on `StackOverflow`. You will definably find the answer. Please read [SwingUtilities.invokeLater](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196889/swingutilities-invokelater)

Comment: Read [Difference between paint, paintComponent and paintComponents in Swing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389187/difference-between-paint-paintcomponent-and-paintcomponents-in-swing)

Comment: Have a look at [Why does one have to use the paintComponent method to draw in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18005505/why-does-one-have-to-use-the-paintcomponent-method-to-draw-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work for you but try

```
 JPanel panel = new JPanel();
 panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
```

or you could try setting the colour in the JFrame and leaving the colour out of the pannel

```
 JFrame frame = new JFrame();
 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 frame.setTitle("MyFirstFrame");
 frame.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
 frame.setLocation(0,0);
 frame.setSize(150,150);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer to change background color

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

public class ColoredFrame {

  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame( "TestFrame" );
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground( Color.PINK );
        //frame contains nothing, so set size
        frame.setSize( 200, 200 );
        frame.setVisible( true );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
      }
    } );
  }
}
```

Reference of [Robin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9030164/2722799).

Answer (score -1):

As for your `MyPanel` it looks like you didn't set the size so atm it is not visible.
And for your `jFrame` since you override paint, why not try setting `g.setBackground(Color.BLACK);`.

Comment: sizing is the exclusive task of the LayoutManager (which by default is a borderLayout on the contentPane which sizes the center component to fill the container). Plus overriding the frame's paint is the wrong approach - custom painting should be handled in the paintComponent of a component, f.i. MyPanel