# setBackgroundColor is not working

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I'm trying to set JFrame frame a background color, but it is not working.
What am I missing here?
this is the code:

```
public class PingPong extends JPanel{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
Ball ball = new Ball(this); 
Table table = new Table(this);
Player player = new Player(this);
PC pc = new PC(this);

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    table.paint(g);
    ball.repaint(g);
    player.repaint(g);
    pc.repaint(g);

}

public static void main(String[] args){
    /* Creating the frame */
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Ping Pong!");
    frame.setSize(600, 600);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(new PingPong());
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    frame.setVisible(true); 
}
```

}

It just won't change colors..

Comment: It actually works, Just the color is covered by the PingPong object.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029367/java-jframe-background-color-not-working Seems to be your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you add a `JPanel` (PingPong object) to your `JFrame`, the `JPanel` is over the `JFrame`, so the color of the `JFrame` becomes not visible.

Apply `setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);` to your PingPong object.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this:

```
frame.getContentPane().setOpaque(true);
```